# How can i fetch the real-time terminal results of AWS - EC2 executed using SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, frontend, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-ssm

I have a scenario where I'm executing the commands on `EC2` via `AWS-SSM(Systems Manager)`. These are `ML` training commands. So if I want to show the epochs `loss` and `accuracy` information in real-time onto the frontend, I can only show after the `AWS-AnsiblePlaybook` has executed the `task`, where the `task` is logged to `CloudWatch` and I can stream.

But if i want to show it realtime, How can I show it? Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for your use case?  In a bash script, you can add a line like this for user data:

```
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

That will cause the user-data logs to be send to the console, where they will be viewable from the EC2 console by selecting the instance and choosing Instance settings - Get System Log.  So if you take wherever you are logging your commands and redirect it similarly to the console, that should give you access to the real-time logs.

Or will using S3 work, like outlined at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/streaming-aws-systems-manager-run-command-output-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/ ?

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the recommendation